# BES Express - failed to run Administration Service

Tags: tomcat, blackberry, bes

I have installed BES Express on Windows Server 2008 SP1 with Exchange 2007 following by [RIM tutorial](https://www.blackberry.com/blackberrytraining/web/_content/indexExternal.html?cc=3731382d30323339305f42455358496e7374616c6c&cx=3230393930393136&cl=656e)

JDK 1.6.18, JDK\bin included into Path variable

After reboot I've run Blackberry Administration Service and receive such error in browser window:

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.hivemind.ApplicationRuntimeException: Missing classpath resource '/com/rim/bes/bas/web/adminconsole/pages/login/SystemError.page'. [context:/WEB-INF/webAdminConsole.application, line 25, column 37]
 org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.WebRequestServicerPipelineBridge.service(WebRequestServicerPipelineBridge.java:60)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c397.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c397.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.request.DecodedRequestInjector.service(DecodedRequestInjector.java:55)
 $ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c393.service($ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c393.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.multipart.MultipartDecoderFilter.service(MultipartDecoderFilter.java:52)
 $ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c391.service($ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c391.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.SetupRequestEncoding.service(SetupRequestEncoding.java:53)
 $ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c395.service($ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c395.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c305.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c305.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.ApplicationServlet.doService(ApplicationServlet.java:123)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.BASApplicationServlet.doService(BASApplicationServlet.java:153)
 org.apache.tapestry.ApplicationServlet.doGet(ApplicationServlet.java:79)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.console.LoginDispatcher.processRequest(LoginDispatcher.java:146)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.console.LoginDispatcher.doGet(LoginDispatcher.java:79)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.ResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersFilter.java:85)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.console.VSJSupportFilter.doFilter(VSJSupportFilter.java:228)
 org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)


root cause 

org.apache.hivemind.ApplicationRuntimeException: Missing classpath resource '/com/rim/bes/bas/web/adminconsole/pages/login/SystemError.page'. [context:/WEB-INF/webAdminConsole.application, line 25, column 37]
 org.apache.tapestry.error.ExceptionPresenterImpl.presentException(ExceptionPresenterImpl.java:64)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.CommonExceptionPresenter.presentException(CommonExceptionPresenter.java:269)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.CommonExceptionPresenter.presentException(CommonExceptionPresenter.java:113)
 $ExceptionPresenter_12d51b7c2cf.presentException($ExceptionPresenter_12d51b7c2cf.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.engine.AbstractEngine.activateExceptionPage(AbstractEngine.java:121)
 org.apache.tapestry.engine.AbstractEngine.service(AbstractEngine.java:280)
 org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.InvokeEngineTerminator.service(InvokeEngineTerminator.java:60)
 $WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3b5.service($WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3b5.java)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.console.ObjectCacheServiceFilter.service(ObjectCacheServiceFilter.java:72)
 $WebRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c3b9.service($WebRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c3b9.java)
 $WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3bb.service($WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3bb.java)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.ServiceFilter.service(ServiceFilter.java:84)
 $WebRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c3b7.service($WebRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c3b7.java)
 $WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3bb.service($WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3bb.java)
 $WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3b1.service($WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3b1.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.WebRequestServicerPipelineBridge.service(WebRequestServicerPipelineBridge.java:56)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c397.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c397.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.request.DecodedRequestInjector.service(DecodedRequestInjector.java:55)
 $ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c393.service($ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c393.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.multipart.MultipartDecoderFilter.service(MultipartDecoderFilter.java:52)
 $ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c391.service($ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c391.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.SetupRequestEncoding.service(SetupRequestEncoding.java:53)
 $ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c395.service($ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c395.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c305.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c305.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.ApplicationServlet.doService(ApplicationServlet.java:123)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.BASApplicationServlet.doService(BASApplicationServlet.java:153)
 org.apache.tapestry.ApplicationServlet.doGet(ApplicationServlet.java:79)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.console.LoginDispatcher.processRequest(LoginDispatcher.java:146)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.console.LoginDispatcher.doGet(LoginDispatcher.java:79)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.ResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersFilter.java:85)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.console.VSJSupportFilter.doFilter(VSJSupportFilter.java:228)
 org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)


root cause 

org.apache.hivemind.ApplicationRuntimeException: Missing classpath resource '/com/rim/bes/bas/web/adminconsole/pages/login/SystemError.page'. [context:/WEB-INF/webAdminConsole.application, line 25, column 37]
 org.apache.tapestry.asset.ClasspathAssetFactory.createAbsoluteAsset(ClasspathAssetFactory.java:61)
 $AssetFactory_12d51b7c400.createAbsoluteAsset($AssetFactory_12d51b7c400.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.asset.ContextAssetFactory.createAsset(ContextAssetFactory.java:66)
 $AssetFactory_12d51b7c3fe.createAsset($AssetFactory_12d51b7c3fe.java)
 $AssetFactory_12d51b7c404.createAsset($AssetFactory_12d51b7c404.java)
 $AssetFactory_12d51b7c2ff.createAsset($AssetFactory_12d51b7c2ff.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.asset.AssetSourceImpl.findAsset(AssetSourceImpl.java:64)
 $AssetSource_12d51b7c3fa.findAsset($AssetSource_12d51b7c3fa.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.NamespaceResourcesImpl.findSpecificationResource(NamespaceResourcesImpl.java:61)
 org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.NamespaceResourcesImpl.getPageSpecification(NamespaceResourcesImpl.java:71)
 org.apache.tapestry.engine.Namespace.locatePageSpecification(Namespace.java:264)
 org.apache.tapestry.engine.Namespace.getPageSpecification(Namespace.java:172)
 org.apache.tapestry.resolver.PageSpecificationResolverImpl.resolve(PageSpecificationResolverImpl.java:131)
 $PageSpecificationResolver_12d51b7c3f4.resolve($PageSpecificationResolver_12d51b7c3f4.java)
 $PageSpecificationResolver_12d51b7c3f5.resolve($PageSpecificationResolver_12d51b7c3f5.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.pageload.PageSource.getPage(PageSource.java:115)
 $IPageSource_12d51b7c2e5.getPage($IPageSource_12d51b7c2e5.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.engine.RequestCycle.loadPage(RequestCycle.java:268)
 org.apache.tapestry.engine.RequestCycle.getPage(RequestCycle.java:251)
 org.apache.tapestry.error.ExceptionPresenterImpl.presentException(ExceptionPresenterImpl.java:40)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.CommonExceptionPresenter.presentException(CommonExceptionPresenter.java:269)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.CommonExceptionPresenter.presentException(CommonExceptionPresenter.java:113)
 $ExceptionPresenter_12d51b7c2cf.presentException($ExceptionPresenter_12d51b7c2cf.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.engine.AbstractEngine.activateExceptionPage(AbstractEngine.java:121)
 org.apache.tapestry.engine.AbstractEngine.service(AbstractEngine.java:280)
 org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.InvokeEngineTerminator.service(InvokeEngineTerminator.java:60)
 $WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3b5.service($WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3b5.java)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.console.ObjectCacheServiceFilter.service(ObjectCacheServiceFilter.java:72)
 $WebRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c3b9.service($WebRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c3b9.java)
 $WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3bb.service($WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3bb.java)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.ServiceFilter.service(ServiceFilter.java:84)
 $WebRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c3b7.service($WebRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c3b7.java)
 $WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3bb.service($WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3bb.java)
 $WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3b1.service($WebRequestServicer_12d51b7c3b1.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.WebRequestServicerPipelineBridge.service(WebRequestServicerPipelineBridge.java:56)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c397.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c397.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.request.DecodedRequestInjector.service(DecodedRequestInjector.java:55)
 $ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c393.service($ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c393.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.multipart.MultipartDecoderFilter.service(MultipartDecoderFilter.java:52)
 $ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c391.service($ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c391.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.services.impl.SetupRequestEncoding.service(SetupRequestEncoding.java:53)
 $ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c395.service($ServletRequestServicerFilter_12d51b7c395.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c399.java)
 $ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c305.service($ServletRequestServicer_12d51b7c305.java)
 org.apache.tapestry.ApplicationServlet.doService(ApplicationServlet.java:123)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.BASApplicationServlet.doService(BASApplicationServlet.java:153)
 org.apache.tapestry.ApplicationServlet.doGet(ApplicationServlet.java:79)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.console.LoginDispatcher.processRequest(LoginDispatcher.java:146)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.console.LoginDispatcher.doGet(LoginDispatcher.java:79)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.common.ResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersFilter.java:85)
 com.rim.bes.bas.web.console.VSJSupportFilter.doFilter(VSJSupportFilter.java:228)
 org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Can you help me?

Thank you!
[same question on bbforums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Professional-Software/BES-Express-fail-to-start-Administration-Service/td-p/716935)

Comment: Did you try running it as Administrator?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with account from Administrators group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to perform clean reinstall, using following article:
[KB04096 - Perform a clean uninstall of the BlackBerry Enterprise Server software](http://www.port3101.org/featured-blackberry-kb-articles/5-kb04096-perform-clean-uninstall-blackberry-enterprise-server-software.html)
But in the progress of that (while searching of "Blackberry Enterprise Server" Value in Registry) I have found some RIM Values in Installer\Folders Key left after uninstall. I have removed them also.

New installation works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

4 Days working on this, anyone still stuck check out this solution:

If you loaded the SQLEXPRESS open SQL Server Configuration Manager for sqlexpress, click on protocols for blackberry, open tcpip, click the TCP/IP properties tab.

Check the IP address for each and every network connection, enable or not, check the IP Address field, should point to your server IP address, any that are not change them to your server IP.

Restart the SQL Services, and all blackberry services, your admin page should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Check the webconsole and other related apps or services have been installed and configured.

It looks like the webconsole is missing a component but can't give you a proper error message because of a programming bug.

BES errors can be a real hoot because they seem to be even less source-related than windows errors.

Comment: All Blackberry services are up and running, SQL TCP\IP protocol is enabled. 
I am able to log in to "BlackBerry Web Desktop Manager" but still I can't log in to "BlackBerry Administration Service".

Answer (score 1):

If you have IIS on same server, you could have a port conflict on 443.

Here are the instructions for changing the port for BlackBerry Device Service:

1. Navigate to Start > Programs > BlackBerry Device Service > BlackBerry Server Configuration Panel > Administration Service
2. Modify the HTTPS Port number to 663 port number
3. Click Apply
4. Click Synchronize
5. Restart the BlackBerry Administration Service Application Server (BAS-AS) and the BlackBerry Administration Service Native Code Container (BAS-NCC) services

The Server address will now be: `https://ServerName:663/webconsole/login`.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no such thing as Windows Server 7, I'm assuming you mean Windows 7 and since Windows 7 isn't listed as a supported host OS for BESX, that would be my guess as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: my apologizes, it's Windows Server 2008 SP1